# Is it ok to limit subclass of an abstract class?

Tags: python

I have an abstract class called Event which i use for all the kind of events in my system - logs, requestes, responses and so on.

One of the parameters of this class is named ids and its' type is a list of strings or just a single string.

I have a conflict which I'm not sure how to solve.
I want requests to be able to get a list of ids, but responses should of only 1 id at a time.

If the system gets a requests with 4 ids it will return 4 different responses, 1 for each id.
Is it ok to limit Response class to only get 1 id?
Or maybe I shouldn't inherit from the abstract Event class?

This is basically the code, of course the class are different.

```py
from abc import ABC
from typing import Union, List
class Event(ABC)
    def __init__(self, ids=Union[List[str],str]):
        self.ids = ids
```

```py
from typing import Union, List
class Request()
    def __init__(self, ids=Union[List[str],str]):
        super().__init__(ids)
```

```py
from typing import Union, List
class Response()
    def __init__(self, ids=str):
        super().__init__(ids)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide MRE. See how to formulate questions fully in order to receive good answers - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I would simply make all three take a `List[str]`, and have `Response` to raise an exception if `ids` has more than one item.

Comment: @chepner Is it ok that the subclass limits the parent? Because if people won't read the code they will wouldn't understand why the class has a parameter named ids, which implies it should be a list, but it raises and exception if it has more than one item.

Comment: Documentation is key. Users may not read the code, but they are responsible for the results if you document that `Response` only works with a singleton list and they pass a longer list anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't change the type of an attribute, since you don't necessarily know *which* class `super()` will resolve to at run-time. Instead, make `ids` *always* be a list, and let `Response` deal with a too-long list at runtime.

```
from abc import ABC
from typing import Union, List

class Event(ABC)
    def __init__(self, ids: List[str]):
        self.ids = ids


class Request(Event)
    def __init__(self, ids: List[str]):
        super().__init__(ids)


class Response(Event)
    def __init__(self, ids: List[str]):
        if len(ids) > 1:
            # We'll call it a type error as if we were distinguishing 
            # singleton lists from arbitrary lists at the type level
            raise TypeError
        super().__init__(ids)
```

Alternatively, you could simply drop all but the first ID (`super().__init__(ids[:1])`), but that could lead to harder-to-debug errors.

You might also consider separate constructors that hide direct access to `Event.__init__`.

```
class Response(Event)
    def __init__(self, ids: List[str]):
        if len(ids) > 1:
            raise TypeError("Too many ids")
        super().__init__(ids)

    @classmethod
    def from_id(cls, id: str):
        return cls([id])
```

Then you always create a response using `Response.from_id("foo")` rather than `Response(["foo"])`.

Comment: Well I guess it does sound a legitimate solution. Also I didn't know that i should raise a type error on this case. Thank you very much!

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should probably raise a ValueError. However, this is very reminiscent of a [dependent type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), in which the values belonging to the type are allowed to depend on another value. Lists of a specific size are one of the canonical examples of dependent types.